# insert query on mysql - WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM training2subjects WHERE trainingID = 3 AND subj' at line 1

when i lunch this query on mysql -

```
INSERT INTO training2subjects ( trainingID, subjectID ) 
VALUES ( 3, 5 ) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM training2subjects 
        WHERE trainingID = 3 
        AND subjectID = 5 
        LIMIT 0,1 
    )
```

When i run the sub-query it works fine

```
SELECT * 
        FROM training2subjects 
        WHERE trainingID = 3 
        AND subjectID = 5 
        LIMIT 0,1
```

I want to insert only if the same data doesn't already exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `INSERT INTO - SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO training2subjects ( trainingID, subjectID ) 
SELECT 3, 5 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM training2subjects 
                  WHERE trainingID = 3 AND subjectID = 5);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b465b441b48701d2e3005305ba7cc22)**

Comment: Hi. no, still error - `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM training2subjects ' at line 3`